# Convert project Qt to file .exe for window

Tags: qt, qt4.7

Hello i'm a young develop on Qt. I want to know that can we convert project Qt (header, source, form, resource) to a file can run without Qt Creator? And how can we convert it to a file executable on window (.exe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is responsible for making an executable out of the source code. This has nothing to do with Qt.
When you start a program from the QtCreator an executable file is built by the compiler, then started. Have a look in your project folder to find that .exe file.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to do anything special. Each Qt project has a .pro file that is used for compiling. You need to use qmake on the command line with the .pro file as input. This will generate a makefile that you can then give to nmake.exe (if using Visual Studio compilers) or mingw-make (if you are uisng mingw compilers) to build. These steps will compile your source code into the .exe. Look through documentation of qmake to know more. Qt Creator also does the same steps and you can check out the buildlog in Qt Creator to see it working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the exe file that you compile with Qt Creator or alternatively some other IDE or compiler is technically all you need to run the project from there on, except you need to have the linked Qt libraries somehow available to the executable. This is especially important if you plan to run it on a machine different from the one you developed it on. See the Qt documentation on [Deploying Qt Applications](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/deployment.html) for other details you may need to consider in that case.